# Additional processor needed for WiFi-MCU module?

Tags: ethernet, wifi, phy, mac

I'm reading up on the design of WiFi-to-Ethernet converters, and came across the [Ubiquiti U6-LR Teardown](https://www.mbreviews.com/ubiquiti-u6-lr-unifi-6-long-range-review/).

I noticed that both this device and its competitors have not just a WiFi-enabled MCU and PHY, but also include an additional processor with at least 512 MB of RAM.

If you were just looking to convert a WiFi signal to Ethernet, is this additional processor really necessary?

I'm Surprised you can't get away with a WiFi + MCU module linked to a PHY directly. I do not have experience in this area of electronics, so any support would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: This thing is not a "Wifi-to-Ethernet converter", but a full-blown router and access point. And quite fancy one. Even simplest routers need to run some kind of operating system, such as Linux on board with different applications, such as firewall, dynamic DNS service client, web/DHCP/telnet/ssh servers and such.

Comment: Speed is probably a big consideration. How fast can an ESP32 process packets? Likely not fast enough - you want something designed for the purpose instead

Comment: @EugeneSh and user253751 (only let me tag one of you) Ahh ok thank you for these comments! If you were looking at purely extending the range of a WiFi network would the added CPU be necessary? Or do you think you could get by with just the MCU-WiFi Module funneling data back to the main router